# Replace white spaces in <td> tag with "."

Tags: html, css

I am interested to resolve next problem with php:

I use php to fill out table in html page,using data from MySql.That is all fine,but I need to use " . " to fill spaces between name and value. I wrote a very simple sample,just to show where is problem.

```
//values in database:
    $name1=Weight of bag        $value1=100
    $name2= Bag type            $value2=Oval


<table>
<tr> 
<td>$name1</td>
<td>$value1</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>$name2</td>
<td>$value2</td>
</tr>
etc...
</table>
```

All is fine on result page, I get all data from database in this format:

```
    Weight of bag        100
    Bag type            Oval
```

I need result to be like this:

```
 Weight of bag........100
 Bag type............Oval
```

My problem is to fill right side of first  tag  with ".", and left side of second  tag. I try some of basic PHP functions, but withouth result.

Thanx

Comment: on trigger of wat event should i replace blank space with .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill remaining table cell with a row of dots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101188/fill-remaining-table-cell-with-a-row-of-dots)

Comment: Tnx! I will try. Tnx again!

Comment: Jeah, I see that now,my mistake..

Comment: Actually there's no need to do that; as MoshMage pointed out, your question has already been answered.

Comment: Try doing it properly using CSS. Checkout ans below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> `<?php
>       $input  = 'Weight of bag        100';
>       echo $output = preg_replace('/(?:\s\s+|\n|\t)/', '......', $input);
>   ?>`

Result is like this

Weight of bag......100

Answer (score 1):

**Try below:**

```
<style type="text/css">
table {
    width: 200px;
}
td span {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
td.name:before {
    clip: rect(0px, 190px, 20px, 0px);
    content: " ............................................................ ";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
td.amt {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><span>Weight of bag</span></td>
        <td class="amt"><span>100</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name"><span>Bag type</span></td>
        <td class="amt"><span>Oval</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/zc27c/1/

Comment: Happy to help. Kindly accept the answer for future use to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of tables, output this in monospaced font and fill it with dots manually.

Here's the function that can fill with dots: http://php.net//manual/ru/function.str-pad.php#81944

```
function pad_between_strings($string1, $string2, $length, $char = " ") {
    $fill_length = $length - ( strlen($string1) + strlen($string2) );
    return $string1 . str_repeat($char, $fill_length) . $string2;
}
```

Comment: This is actually hella smart!

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
<tr> 
<td>$name1........</td>
<td>$value1.......</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>........$name2</td>
<td>........$value2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```